# How to access system right click menus?

Tags: vb.net, right-click

**My Project**: Instant web searching tool

**Problem**: I want users to be able to search the web for selected text via a right click. An appropriate example would be WinRar. When we right click a file, the right click menu has  an option to Archive that particular file. I want to add that type of option.

Is there any way?

Comment: In Chrome Browser, you can select text and right click >> search Google for the selected text. Are you trying to add similar functionality to Windows?

Comment: Are you talking about the one in Windows Explorer? That is called a "context menu", which should give you something to search for here.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/